# SSJS onClick function in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, onclick

I'd like to use the onClick Event on the a element in Marketing Cloud to create a new field in a data extensions when clicked and later fill out this field with a letter A.

For now I focused on creating a new field in a data extension when the element a is clicked and added this script to the head of my HTML code:

```
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

    Platform.Load("core","1.1");

  function myFunction() {
  var de = DataExtension.Init('dataextension_externalkey');

    try {
        var newField = {
   Name : "NewFieldV2",
   CustomerKey : "dataextension_externalkey",
   FieldType : "Text",
   IsRequired: true,
   DefaultValue: "textexample"
};
        var status = de.Fields.Add(newField);
        Write("(+) Data Extension was created successfully." + "<br>");
    } catch (err) {
        Write("(!) Data Extension was not created. Error message: " + err + "<br>")
    }    
}
    
</script>
```

and this is my element a

```
<a href="salesforce.stackexchange.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #f4f4f4; width: auto; width: auto;" id="myButton" onclick="MyFunction()"><strong>Find out more</strong></a>
```

It doesn't work and I'm stuck with the question if what I want to achieve is even possible?

Comment: Server-Side JavaScript compiles and runs _before_ the page is displayed, while client-side JavaScript runs after the page has loaded.  Click events are _client-side_ activities.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, your challenge is to process input from a webform.
Let's call it "form".

Server-Sided javascript is server-sided code that is executed *only* when your form is loaded from the server.

Contrary to that, a javascript function that fires when the client presses a button - which means it is executing AFTER the form has been loaded from the server, is *client-side* Javascript that does not directly interact with the server. (client = the machine used by whoever fills in the form)

Which means server-side code is simply not executed when you want it (onclick).
To leverage Server-Side Javascript (or AMPScript, for that matter) you will have to make sure the page containing your server sided code is *loaded*.

Let's call this page handling the server side actions a "handler".
Because in the simplest usecase you set up a separate handler page that is called when the button is pressed.

Check the diagram here.

[Issue with passing value to data extension from the marketing cloud page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312937/issue-with-passing-value-to-data-extension-from-the-marketing-cloud-page/312954?noredirect=1#comment466552_312954)

To avoid sending the user across millions of pages, you can also send the data to the form itself, and incorporate handler functionality.
The key for executing SSJS is to reload the form. For usability, prefill the fields the user has already entered and keep going from there.

So:

- Your form runs server-sided code ONLY when it loads.
- Every other server sided action after that has to be done on a handler because it requires being loaded from the server.
- You can make your form send data to itself to make it act as a handler, but you will have to reload it every time you want server-side code to execute.

There are solutions around this, but they typically involve Ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp